# ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, installation

I use Jupyter Notebook, on a Windows 10 machine, (without anaconda)

so far I've had no problems installing my libraries except for tensorflow. I tried this :

```
!pip install tensorflow
```

(and also without the exclamation point but pip wasn't recognized)
and I had the following error :

Collecting tensorflow
Using cached
https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/af/50/d7da24189d95e2084bb1cc
350a8e4acdf1b0c9b3d57def7a348f0d9cb062/tensorflow-2.2.0-cp37-
cp37m-win_amd64.whl
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno
28] No space left on device

I saw that I could give more memory to the tmp on forums, but it's always adapted to Ubuntu distributions and it does not work on my machine.

If you have any idea how I could install Tensorflow it would be wonderful!

Have a nice day.

Comment: mate!! No space left on device, free up some space first

Comment: Thanks E.Serra! I freed up space, but now I have this error : ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow

Comment: For the last issue, I had to put this into the prompt and that worked, I could install tensorflow :  pip3 install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl

Comment: However when I import keras I have this error : ImportError: Keras requires TensorFlow 2.2 or higher. Install TensorFlow via `pip install tensorflow` But I already install tensorflow with pip install tensorflow!!

Comment: do a pip freeze and check your version of tensorflow, best route is to probably start again, or install keras first (that will install whatever version of tensorflow you need bypassing your pain)

Comment: @Chaussette, confirm that you are using the 64 bit version of python as this is a requirement for tensorflow ? There is a workaround try conda install if you are using anaconda `conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow`. Keras are tightly integrated with tensorflow from 2.3 version onwards. There is no need of keras import, instead you can use module ` tf.keras`. For more details please refer [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras). Thanks!

Comment: TFer2 & E.Serra Thanks for you answers! Finally I switched to linux (for other reasons) and everything works like clockwork.